# Calculate average from MutableCollection<Any!>?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have just started utilizing a Firestore server to store values from my android app. I have retrieved these values and now want to calculate an average from them. My original Idea was to get the values, convert them to a float (there are decimals so I am guessing this is the best format) and then calculate an average to display. However parts of this isn't working so I am wondering if there is a more optimal way.

Current code:

```
val map = document.data?.values //gets values from the hashmap
Log.d("firestore", "values1 = $map")
val map2 = map.toString() //converts them to string
Log.d("firestore", "values2 = $map2")
val map3 = map2.toFloat() //converts them to a float??
Log.d("firestore", "values3 = $map3")
```

The float section also returns random digits, for example the string is `[5.0, 5.0]` and the float returns `[91.0, 53.0, 46.0, 48.0, 44.0, 32.0, 53.0, 46.0, 48.0, 93.0]`. Any help on how I could convert the values so I can calculate the average of the values, would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide the input (`document.data`) and the actual log output? It would help your understanding just as much anyone offering answer also to see the Kotlin inferred data types.

I assume the first variable `map` is `MutableCollection<Any!>` from your question.  Calling it `map` is misleading since `map` is a key/value construct that requires two types to describe it.

When you call `toString()` on a `Collection` you are going to get a String representation.  So I can believe the output is indeed `[5.0, 5.0]`.  It then makes no sense trying to convert that to float, as this whole string is not a float.

You are going about this the wrong way.

First you need to convert the `Collection<Any!>` into a strongly typed array so you can do proper maths on it.

Let's start with some data we can see

```
val source : MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf("n1" to 2.0, "n2" to 3.5, "s1" to "fish", "n3" to 4.5)
val listOfAll: MutableCollection<Any> = source.values
println("listOfAll=$listOfAll")
```

This produces

```
listOfAll=[2.0, 3.5, fish, 4.5]
```

We can't perform calculations, so let's just filter out anything that is not a number

```
val listOfOnlyNumbers = listOfAll.filterIsInstance<Number>()
println("listOfOnlyNumbers=$listOfOnlyNumbers")
```

This produces

```
listOfOnlyNumbers=[2.0, 3.5, 4.5]
```

Now there is an in-built average function but `Number` is abstract so we need cast to a concrete class.  `Float` would do, but most would normally use `Double` (lower precision than `Float`).  If these values are `Decimal` in origin `BigDecimal` is better as it is optimised for decimals so you don't get `12.340000000000001` kind of thing.

```
val listOfDoubles = listOfOnlyNumbers.map { it.toDouble() }
val average = listOfDoubles.average()
println("average=$average")
```

Which produces what you may want

```
average=3.3333333333333335
```

(taking care that the original collection had one more value which is not taken into consideration for the average division)

So in summary what you want comes down to

```
val average = document.data?.values
   .filterIsInstance<Number>()
   .map { it.toDouble() }
   .average()
```